# swagger-maven-plugin generated json file doesn't match "http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs" json file

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, swagger

I'm using swagger-maven-plugin in my pom.xml file as follows

```
 <plugin>
 <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
 <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.8</version>
 .....
 </plugin>
```

It does generate a swagger.json file but it is of the form

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "description" : .......,
  ......
}
```

However, the json file generated at http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs with swaggerUI is of the form

```
{
  "openapi":"3.0.1","info":{"title":"OpenAPI definition",......
   ....
}
```

Moreover, the swagger.json file generated with the plugin completely ignores the path parameters defined in Spring annotations and therefore doesn't generate the right output file. How do I make sure that the generated swagger.json file matches the json file at http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs and doesn't ignore the parameters? Also why does it use Swagger 2 format even when version specified is 3.1.8?

Comment: Any update? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857955/swagger-maven-plugin-generated-json-file-doesnt-match-http-localhost8080-v3